# How to create a material with fading edges effect?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I am trying to make a fresnel kind of effect that only is visible on the edges of an object. Kind of like a fading outline. So I tried to take the angle between the camera normal and object normal and depending on the size of the angle I want another color. This is how my shader graph looks like

[image]

I'm not sure if the vectors are normalized, hence the normalization nodes. Also not sure if the vector transformations from different spaces are correct, but I think so. The result looks like something I'm trying to achieve, but it's not so easy to see. Is there a way to visualize it better or "debug" the shader? And is this a correct setup for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: May I ask why didn't you just use the fresnel node as a factor?

Comment: @Georges doesn’t the fresnel node just act like a ”shell” on the object? I mean if I put it on a sphere it ads value not only on the outlines, but to the middle facing the camera as well? Sorry, if I aint making myself clear

Comment: You can try it yourself, just add a "Layer Weight" node from input in the shader editor, you can use either "Facing" or "Fresnel" Ctrl+Shift+RMB on the node to see it's effect in the viewport in render mode, if you need more control you can add a "Color Ramp" node. I usually use this node combination as a factor between two shaders or two textures. "Fersnel" is supposed to be more physically accurate, but sometimes I find "Facing" provides me better with the effect I'm after, so you need to experiment with these.